# Switching to Java 17 breaks Gradle testDebug task

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-17

We have an Android project with various Gradle subprojects. For years we've been using the task `testDebug` to run all the tests in all subprojects.

However, since we recently switched to Java 17, we get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'testDebug' is ambiguous in root project 'tv' and its subprojects. Candidates are: 'testDebugUnitTest', 'testDevAndroidDebugUnitTest', 'testDevAndroidtvDebugUnitTest', 'testDevFireDebugUnitTest', 'testDevFiretvDebugUnitTest', 'testProdAndroidDebugUnitTest', 'testProdAndroidtvDebugUnitTest', 'testProdFireDebugUnitTest', 'testProdFiretvDebugUnitTest', 'testShopAndroidtvDebugUnitTest', 'testShopFiretvDebugUnitTest', 'testSitAndroidDebugUnitTest', 'testSitAndroidtvDebugUnitTest', 'testSitFireDebugUnitTest', 'testSitFiretvDebugUnitTest'.
```

When I switch back to Java 11:

```
➜  tv git:(master) export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home

➜  tv git:(master) java --version                                                                         
openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.17.8.1 (build 11.0.17+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.17.8.1 (build 11.0.17+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

The task works again:

```
➜  tv git:(master) ./gradlew --dry-run testDebug | grep testDebug
// ...
:watchlist-feature:data:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED
:watchlist-feature:repository:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED
:watchlist-feature:usecase:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED
:features-common:start-page:data:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED
:features-common:start-page:interactor:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED
:features-common:start-page:presentation:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED
:features-tv:start-page:presentation:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED
```

Of course, I could now enumerate all the specific test tasks instead but that promises to be a maintenance nightmare...

UPDATE: This was tested and is reproducible with both AGP 7.4.2/Gradle 7.6.1 and AGP 8.0.0/Gradle 8.0 (except that, for the latter combination Java 11 doesn't work at all, but that's expected).

Comment: @Robert - good point, I've added the information as an update! (This was tested and is reproducible with both AGP 7.4.2/Gradle 7.6.1 and AGP 8.0.0/Gradle 8.0.)